# Output TukeyHSD or model.tables output as tables using xtable

Tags: r, r-markdown, xtable

I'm dealing with ANOVA tables which I am outputting in my R Markdown using `xtable` and outputting to PDF.

However, when I'm using functions like `TukeyHSD` or `model.tables` to do comparative analysis, `xtable` is giving me the error (in the case of `model.tables`):

> Error in UseMethod("xtable") :    no applicable method for 'xtable'
>   applied to an object of class "c('tables_aov', 'list.of')"

How do I get around this?

I'm trying to find a way to output these in a way that isn't just basic R output but I'm running in to this problem with any of the other packages like `texreg` or `stargazer`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a package called `broom` which will convert your model results into a data.frame. A reproducible example from package documentation. You can use `xtable` on the dataframe object

```
> library(broom)

> fm1 <- aov(breaks ~ wool + tension, data = warpbreaks)
> thsd <- TukeyHSD(fm1, "tension", ordered = TRUE)
> tidy(thsd)
  comparison  estimate   conf.low conf.high adj.p.value
1        M-H  4.722222 -4.6311985  14.07564 0.447421021
2        L-H 14.722222  5.3688015  24.07564 0.001121788
3        L-M 10.000000  0.6465793  19.35342 0.033626219)
```

Comment: Works perfectly for TukeyHSD but getting an error for model.table for the same reason xtable was failing before: "cannot coerce class "c("tables_aov", "list.of")" to a data.frame"

Comment: some how you have to convert model.table object to a data.frame. I dnt know exactly how but this [https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMark/RMark.pdf] package might help

Comment: Still not working but the only reason I was using it at all was to pad out the analysis with everything we'd covered. Figuring Tukey's meets exactly what the model.tables was attempting to. Thanks!